# Location-Manager not returning location consistently

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, location, geocoder

I am using Network Provider to get the last known location of the user. When I tested it, It was working perfectly in one of my phones, but latitude and longitude is returning null on another phone. Is there an alternative to location manager to get a more consistent result. Or is there some other bug in my code

Here is my Permission checking Code:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                applicationContext,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle("Please Grant Location Permissions")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                .show()
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),
                101
            )
        }
```

And my location request code

```
 longitude =
            locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)?.longitude
        latitude =
            locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)?.latitude
        val geocoder = Geocoder(this)
        if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
            val addresses: List<Address> = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)
            val cityName = addresses[0].subAdminArea
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

As documentations says

> Gets the last known location from the given provider, or null if there is no last known location. The returned location may be quite old in some circumstances, so the age of the location should always be checked.
> This will never activate sensors to compute a new location, and will only ever return a cached location.
> See also getCurrentLocation(String, CancellationSignal, Executor, Consumer) which will always attempt to return a current location, but will potentially use additional power in the course of the attempt as compared to this method.
> Params:
> provider – a provider listed by getAllProviders()
> Returns:
> the last known location for the given provider, or null if not available
> Throws:
> SecurityException – if no suitable permission is present
> IllegalArgumentException – if provider is null or doesn't exist

so in case if last location return null you must request new on or custom handler